# ImageView shows nothing

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have a `Bitmap` (1538 x 2000) and set it as `src` of `ImageView` but when I run the app nothing shows up (but the activity background color), I read things about bitmap dimension limits, But if the problem is the limitation why I can view this bitmap by the gallery on the same device?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pic3"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you post your xml layout?

Comment: try to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for big images

Comment: I think you are getting BitmapOutofMemory exception, scale down your bitmap and use in the imageview.

Comment: it is the problem with image size. Gallery must be handling this in some way

Comment: tnx for quick respond, @SilvansSolanki no exception occured, app runs just image view looks empty!

Comment: There should be an exception, if you check your logcat then you will get the exception. without exception what is the reason image is not showing?

Comment: I tried smaller size and it worked fine, All i'm asking is how can I use orginal size, the way android gallery does that?

Comment: The reason of your image not showing in only BOM error. you need to deal with it and need to show reduced image in imageview.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki, right, I got this in logcat : "OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2307x3000, max=2048x2048)", but it's a little confusing, my image size actually is smaller than this

Comment: can you post your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is my abuse of `drawable` folders without considering android behavior, I put the image in the `drawable` folder which android assumes it's proper for `mdpi` devices.

My logcat was pointing at this before :

```
OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2307x3000, max=2048x2048)
```

As you can see the original size was (1538x2000) and logcat reports it (2307x3000) which means android scales (1.5x) my image to fit my `hdpi` device and when I load it using assets as @Prakhar- the scarlett speedstr said, It worked how i expected without android interference.

Also I tried more and put the image in the `drawable-hdpi` and it worked fine without any scale.

Thanks for your helpful answers and comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

put the image in the assets folder

```
src->main->assets
```

If the folder is not there, create it.

After putting the image there, use this code in java (setting image programmatically).

```
Drawable d = null;
    try {
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"), null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Make sure you add the extension also when you use image name. eg: background.jpg or backgroung.png.

this should work.

Comment: tnx @Shree , It worked,But I'm wondering why it was largening my bitmap and now the size is exact as the orginal version is

Comment: @Farshad honestly, I am also not clear about this, but I faced this problem with big images. In devices with high ram and processor, it was working fine, but in other devices, it was either blank or the app was crashing. When I did programmatically, it worked. I tried to read about this, didn't understand much... but it has to do something with the allocation of cache memory

Comment: The image was in the drawable folder, considering the logcat message android scales it 1.5 times that I don't know why! But when I load it as asset the result dimension is what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for image sizes in android. It's usually 2048 (max dimension), but you can get the device's specific value with these methods: `Canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth(), Canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight()`

Your image size seems ok, but maybe it's in a wrong drawable folder (and because of this the android read it with higher resolution). You can put the image to the `drawable-nodpi` (more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) folder to be sure it won't up/downscaled, but I personally think it would be better to use lower resolutions, maybe in multiple folders (or a vector assets, if the image is available in SVG)